# Can you delay until you are no longer dazed?

Tags: dnd-4e, conditions, initiative

I use a power that says "Target creature is *dazed* until the end of your next turn" against a monster that acts just before me in the initiative order.

Can the monster *delay* its turn until my next turn elapses in order to have a full turn, unhindered by the *daze*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**

Most conditions, including Dazed, end whenever the effect that created them says they do.

If Player dazes Enemy until the end of Player's next turn, then the condition ends at the end of Player's next turn. It could also end if another, more specific effect ends it, like one of Enemy's or their allies' abilities. It would also end if Player delays *their* turn, as explicitly spelled out in the rules section concerning the Delay action (Rules Compendium, pg 242):

> At the moment the creature delays, any effect that it has been sustaining ends. In addition, effects that last until the end of the creature’s turn now end if they are beneficial to it and its allies—they cannot be prolonged by delaying. For instance, **if the creature stunned an enemy until the end of its next turn, the stunned condition ends as soon as the creature delays**.

Note that this rule applies when the stunning creature delays, not when the stunned creature delays.

So, it goes like this:

1. Player dazes Enemy until the end of Player's next turn.
2. Everyone else goes in turn order, until Enemy's turn, right before Player's turn.
3. Enemy's turn starts, but Enemy delays with a free action.
4. Player takes their turn. If they delay, the daze effect on Enemy ends immediately. If they don't delay, the daze effect ends at the end of their turn.
5. Enemy takes their turn. They will now be *after* player in the initiative order. The daze effect has ended, so they are not dazed and get all their actions.

Answer (score 1):

Delay [[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=327)] (PHB p.288, RC p.241):

> A creature can choose to wait to take its turn until later in a round. It might want to see what actions its allies take so that it can plan tactics, or it could be waiting for enemies to move into range.
>
> Delay Turn
>
> - Action: Free action. A creature can take this action only when its turn is about to start.
> - Delay until Later Initiative: The creature delays its turn until it decides to act later in the initiative order. However, parts of the creature’s turn occur the moment the creature delays, as detailed below.
> - Returning to the Initiative Order: After any turn has been completed, the creature can step back into the initiative order and take its turn. The creature’s initiative changes to this new position in the initiative order.
> - Start of Turn: The start of the creature’s turn occurs when the creature delays, not when it later takes its turn. Thus, **effects that are triggered by the start of the turn still take place—they can’t be avoided by delaying.**
> - End of Turn: The end of the creature’s turn gets split in two: One part occurs when the creature delays, and the second part when it later takes its delayed turn. Different things occur at each of those times.
>
>   End of Turn when the Creature Delays: At the moment the creature delays, **any effect that it has been sustaining ends.** In addition, effects that last until the end of the creature’s turn now end **if they are beneficial to it and its allies—they cannot be prolonged by delaying.** For instance, if the creature stunned an enemy until the end of its next turn, the stunned condition ends as soon as the creature delays.
>
>   End of Turn after the Creature Acts: **After the creature returns to the initiative order and takes its delayed turn, it makes the saving throws it normally makes at the end of its turn.** In addition, **harmful effects that last until the end of the creature’s turn now end—they cannot be avoided by delaying.** For instance, if the creature is weakened until the end of its next turn, the weakened condition ends only after it acts.
> - Losing a Delayed Turn: If the creature doesn’t take its delayed turn before its initiative comes back up in the order, it loses the delayed turn, and its initiative remains where it was.

Emphasis added.

In short, delaying your turn cannot be used to avoid things like ongoing damage, cannot be used to sustain positive effects for longer, and cannot be used to avoid the consequences of negative effects.

Also note that some conditions (such as Stunned) prevent taking a free action, which would prevent the turn delay from occurring at all. (The Dazed condition, however, does not prevent free actions.)

Comment: Are all parts of this necessary to quote? For the purposes of [Fair Use](http://fairuse.stanford.edu/overview/fair-use/what-is-fair-use/), I suggest you consider whether some of this rule can be left unquoted, under the assumption the asker can look them up if given a page number or book reference.

Comment: IANAL, so I'm not going to try and argue about what is and is not legally Fair Use; it would only be speculation. You're welcome to edit it if you feel the quote needs to be cut down. However, I do not have a page reference, as my PDFs are not currently available to me, which is why I went with a DDI link instead.

Comment: Doesn't DDI provide page references at the end of an entry?

Comment: Haha, So it does!

Comment: The rules say that "harmful effects that last until the end of the creature's turn" end later. It says nothing about effects dependant on the attacker's end of turn. The emphasized rules don't really apply to this situation, I think.

Comment: I think @PetrHudeček is right. If the creature delays until your turn is over, then the condition would have ended by the time it takes its turn. None of this applies to that. Still, it helped me with my related question.

Comment: The Delay section of the Rules Compendium doesn't look any different, so no further guidance there. Also don't see anything in the Conditions section.